# Get files and folders from shared onedrive link for WP10

Tags: uwp, onedrive

I could not able to locate any reference of a method to, using the OneDrive SDK on Windows universal 10 application, to get all the files and folders from shared link. For ex the link
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5D33DD65C6932946!70859&authkey=!AL7N1QAfSWcjNU8&ithint=folder%2cgif is a shared link which has resource being shared and an authentication token that provides access to the resource information.

The referenced Onedrive Sdk is [this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp).

Comment: This functionality is not available via the API at the moment, though it's on the radar. Once the API adds this functionality all of the SDKs will be updated to include it as well.